# Handlebars precompile version error with Ember rc1

Tags: ember.js

Upgrading Ember to 1.0.0-rc1 results in the following error:

```
Uncaught Template was precompiled with an older version of Handlebars 
than the current runtime. Please update your precompiler to a newer 
version (>= 1.0.0-rc.3) or downgrade your runtime to an older version (<= 1.0.rc.2).
```

I am using a version of handlebars that should work according to the error message above:

```
DEBUG: Ember.VERSION : 1.0.0-rc.1 ember.js:339
DEBUG: Handlebars.VERSION : 1.0.0-rc.3 ember.js:339
DEBUG: jQuery.VERSION : 1.9.1
```

I also upgraded my `ember-rails` gem to `0.9.2`

How do I get around this error?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This was caused by `barber` gem which is using handlebars rc2 for template precompilation. [I've made a pull request](https://github.com/tchak/barber/pull/6) which fixes it. If you need this working now, you can just use my fork :)

#### Update: instructions for using darthdeus fork:

1) Add the following to your Gemfile:

```
gem "barber", :git => "git://github.com/darthdeus/barber.git", :branch => "update-handlebars-to-rc3"
```

2) Clear your tmp dir

```
rm -rf tmp
```

3) Restart your server

**edit:** for future readers the changes have been merged now, so using a master branch from the official repo should work.

Comment: In my case simply updating ember-rails bumped barber as well, and that got rid of errors.

Comment: @SeanO'Hara yes you're right, the issue is fixed on master now

Comment: `rm -rf tmp` and restarting my server was enough since the issue was fixed on master... thanks for the hint, it was driving me nuts!