# Ember throws an error because of Handlebars, which is correct version

Tags: ember.js, handlebars.js, dependency-management

Here's the `<head>` of my HTML document.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang='en'>
  <head>
    <link href="/assets/application.css?body=1" media="all" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script src="/assets/modernizr.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="/assets/jquery.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="/assets/handlebars.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script><!-- 1.0.0-rc4 -->
    <script src="/assets/ember.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script><!-- 1.0.0-rc3 -->
    <script src="/assets/ember-data.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

As far as I know, I've put them in the correct order. Ember throws this error:

```
assertion failed: Ember Handlebars requires Handlebars 1.0.0-rc.3 or greater.
```

**But I've included Handlebars 1.0.0-rc4, which should work, according to this error.**

I'm getting Handlebars through the `handlebars-assets` gem, but that shouldn't matter, since it's supposedly the correct version, right?

Following [this SO post's suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14904657/handlebars-precompile-version-error-with-ember-rc1), I ran `rm -rf tmp`, and restarted my server, to no avail.

I also tried deleting the `handlebars-assets` gem and manually including Handlebars 1.0.0-rc4. Same thing.

I tried my best to get a working jsfiddle, but it's not working (apparently because I did it wrong, not related to this issue): it's [here](http://jsfiddle.net/cz3Xv/).

Comment: Can you recreate the issue in a jsfiddle perhaps? (You can load external scripts on the side), I've seen this in a script order issue before, but your order seems ok.

Comment: I tried to get one, but I'm new to Handlebars and Ember, so it's not working, but not because of this problem. It's [here](http://jsfiddle.net/cz3Xv/).

Comment: That seems to work http://jsfiddle.net/cz3Xv/1/ (you forgot to run the script on-dom-loaded)

Comment: You're right. That does seem to work. I wonder what it is, then, if those same versions are in my app.

Answer (score 1):

The problem seams to be that you are using the wrong ember/handlebars files combinations.

> assertion failed: Ember Handlebars requires Handlebars 1.0.0-rc.3 or greater.
>   But I've included Handlebars 1.0.0-rc4, which should work, according to this error.

As far I can see with this [PR](https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/commit/ff52e8b7345df48538b506153bf91202707b525b) in the ember-latest this has been fixed. 
This should work:

- http://builds.emberjs.com/handlebars-1.0.0-rc.4.js
- http://builds.emberjs.com/ember-latest.js
- http://builds.emberjs.com/ember-data-latest.js

you can get here the latest builds: http://builds.emberjs.com

hope it helps